# How to install a google font on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I added the stylesheet in the .info file and pasted in the url for the google font but in firebug it just shows the entire page indicating that it is not linked correctly. How are google font linked in drupal 7?

Answer (score 15):

Add this in your template.php file (located in theme folder) :

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    drupal_add_css('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,700', array('type' => 'external'));
}
```

(replace YOURTHEMENAME with the real name of your theme).

And then the correct css code in your css file. 
Something like :

```
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make you life a lot easier by just using the contributed [Google Fonts module](http://drupal.org/project/google_fonts)...it does everything for you and has been proven to work many times.

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/fontyourface has become the module of choice for adding third party fonts

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use that module, it's not maintained anymore! use fontyourface instead as mentioned by PatrickS

Comment: We've run into performance issues with fontyourface on more complex drupal sites. If you don't need the full suite of functionality, answer #1 is still the best.